# How to turn React RichTextEditor class into a function?

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm using [react-rte](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte) in my project and try to get the text editor working, but with no success. I copied the class from the above website (code below) and tried to turn it into a function, since I have more experience with them. What am I missing?

**Class from `react-rte`-link**

```
class MyStatefulEditor extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    value: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue()
  }

  onChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({value});
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      // Send the changes up to the parent component as an HTML string.
      // This is here to demonstrate using `.toString()` but in a real app it
      // would be better to avoid generating a string on each change.
      this.props.onChange(
        value.toString('html')
      );
    }
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <RichTextEditor
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**And here's my function:**

```
function MyStatefulEditor ({ values, setValues }) {
  const value = RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue();

  console.log(values, setValues);

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    value.toString("html");
  };

  return (
    <RichTextEditor
      value={values.bodyText}
      onChange={handleChange("bodyText")}
      required
      id="body-text"
      name="bodyText"
      className={classes.textField}
      type="string"
      multiline
      rows="20"
      variant="filled"
      style={{ minHeight: 410 }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working, in case anyone is looking for the answer!

```
// values.bodyText has the database information, 
// if I'm not adding a new thing, but editing an old one

<BodyTextEditor
  value={values.bodyText}
  setValue={bodyText => setValues({...values, bodyText })}
/>
```

Function:

```
// some things inside RTE are just for styling, delete the id's etc. 

function BodyTextEditor({ value, setValue }) {

  const [editorValue, setEditorValue] =
    React.useState(RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(value, 'markdown'));

  const handleChange = value => {
    setEditorValue(value);
    setValue(value.toString("markdown"));
  };

  return (
    <RichTextEditor
      value={editorValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      required
      id="body-text"
      name="bodyText"
      type="string"
      multiline
      variant="filled"
      style={{ minHeight: 410 }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RichTextEditor from 'react-rte';

const BodyTextEditor = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue());
  const onChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
    if (props.onChange) {
      props.onChange(value.toString('html'));
    }
  };

  return <RichTextEditor value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

export default BodyTextEditor;
```

You can use this as your child component.